# Behat 3 @Transform

Tags: php, behat

```
/**
 * @Transform :airline
 */
public function castICAOToAirline($airline)
{
    return AirlineQuery::create()->findOneByICAO($airline);
}

/**
 * @Transform :model
 */
public function castModelToAircraftType($model)
{
    return AircraftTypeQuery::create()->findOneByModel($model);
}

/**
 * @Given airline :airline owns an :model with callsign :callsign
 */
public function newAircraftOfAirline(Airline $airline, AircraftType $model, $callsign)
{
    $aircraft = new Aircraft();
    $aircraft->setCallsign($callsign)
        ->setAirline($airline)
        ->setAircraftType($model)
        ->save();
    return $aircraft;
}
```

I have problems with step argument transformations ( http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/2.definitions.html#transforming-tables ). It seems to work for `@Transform :airline` and I think it tries to match both with the first @Transform. However if I try to use `@Transform airline :airline` to specify the call more it's not working either.

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AirlineSteps::newAircraftOfAirline() must be an instance of Model\Airline, string given

Comment: I reverted from 3.0.15 to 3.0.14 what fixed that problem for me so I think there is some kind of a bug and I posted a Bug report on github